# Multiple domains within a school network environment

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, mac-osx, subdomain, mac-osx-server

The work placement I am currently at has two domains a old one and a new one. The new one is pointed to our frog server which hosts our website on our internal network and we have a osx server which uses the old domain.

I have created a subdomain from the new domain we have and pointed it to our WAN address and will be used for the osx server so we can enroll devices and access profile manager.

It has propagated and when I type osx.tworiversschool.net (which is our new subdomain) it goes to our website instead of the osx server like our old domain profileman.tworivers-high.staffs.sch.uk (you can see why we changed it) ;) used it.

We don't know why the old domain profileman.tworivers-high.staffs.sch.uk worked alongside tworiversschool.net where as now that I have created a new subdomain osx.tworiversschool.net and changed the hostname on the osx server to the new subdomain and it no longer working and just directing the subdomain to the website instead.

Any assistance would be welcome.

Thanks
Corey

Comment: It sounds like you're hopelessly out of your depth, no offense.  Probably the best thing you can do is recognize that, and acquire the assistance of someone with some expertise in the areas of DNS and web... stuff.  And OSX server, from the sounds of things.  (Ewww.)

Comment: That's why I asked a question on this website. ;) I have it partially working as it goes to WAN IP. I just need to know how to get it to redirect to the mac mini server. I know this is somehow possible with a proxy which the school defiantly has so ill be looking at that hopefully today if I am not tied up with other issues.

Answer (score 0):

This question is now resolved for me.

The school I work at actually has multiple WAN IP addresses so the osx.tworiversschool.net was pointing at the website WAN address instead of the OSX Server WAN address.